# Why Rsjx switchmap could not return timer(0, 20)?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a Ionic/Angular app where I would like to implement a counter function.
I found one: https://github.com/btroncone/learn-rxjs/blob/master/recipes/smartcounter.md
Good job. all credits to btroncone!

I started to implement this as a component, but facing an errr I don't understand.

This is the code so far:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timer';

@Component({
  selector: 'number-tracker',
  template: `<h3> {{ currentNumber }}</h3>`
})
export class CounterComponent implements OnDestroy {
//export class NumberTrackerComponent implements OnDestroy {
  @Input()
  set end(endRange: number) {
    this._counterSub$.next(endRange);
  }
  public currentNumber = 0;
  private _counterSub$ = new Subject();
  private _subscription : Subscription;

  constructor() {
    this._subscription = this._counterSub$
      .switchMap(endRange => {
        return timer(0, 20)
            .mapTo(this.positiveOrNegative(endRange, this.currentNumber))
            .startWith(this.currentNumber)
            .scan((acc, curr) => acc + curr)
            // .delayWhen(i => {
            //   easing here
            // })
            .takeWhile(this.takeUntilFunc(endRange, this.currentNumber));
      })
      .subscribe(val => this.currentNumber = val);
  }

  private positiveOrNegative(endRange, currentNumber) {
    return endRange > currentNumber ? 1 : -1;
  }

  private takeUntilFunc(endRange, currentNumber) {
    return endRange > currentNumber
      ? val => val <= endRange
      : val => val >= endRange;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

And the error I got is:

[image]

I found an example, but this is returning a observable:

```
clicks.switchMap(click => {
    return Rx.Observable.interval(500)
})
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: It should be `import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer'` and `Observable.timer(0, 20)`.

Answer (score 0):

It was verry simple in the end, I had to add:

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer'
```

All credits to https://github.com/btroncone